# an AJAX link for the dev and prod environments

Tags: ajax, symfony1

I have this line below that shows a link to go the next page of a list.

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('lista_miembros',
'/frontend_dev.php/miembros/filtrar?page=2')">Next page</a>
```

The problem: as expected, it only works in the development environment of
the frontend (frontend_dev.php).

My question: what should I to get it work on both environments
(production and development)? Using if's and getting the environment
being used is the only way, or is there any cooler way?

Comment: the way your link renders (/frontend_dev.php or /frontend_prod.php) should be a function of whatever environment you're in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `url_for()` function to generate your URL in your view.  That way you don't need to worry about the environment, as the url string generated will handle all this for you, eg:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('lista_miembros', '<?php echo url_for("@your_route"); ?>'>Next page</a>
```

Comment: What about when you use urls in code that's placed in .js-files. Is it regarded as the 'right' way to generate the javascript using php and then dynamicly load them in the view so that urls used in ajax-requests are correct?

Comment: @Christopher I tend to use a `<script>` block inline in the page with eg `var myAjaxURL = "<?php echo url_for(...); ?>";` for the various urls required. Not pretty, but it works.. :-)

Comment: @richsage Yeah, I've done that a couple of times myself. Have also used dynamic javascripts and that works as well. The former is by far the easiest though. Thanks for your feedback. :)